# Why was "Rayas" used as the translation in Goonies?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos

I was watching "Goonies" last night, with Spanish subtitles.

When the kids said, "sh*t" it was translated as "Rayas."

Doesn't "Rayas" mean "stripes"?

Why was that word chosen as the translation?

BTW, when an English speaker / Spanish learner wants to practice speaking Spanish with another learner, they could inquire, "Anyone for Tienes?"

Comment: Are you sure it was rayas and not rayos?

Comment: Pretty sure, but what does "rayos" mean?

Comment: "Rayas" as a translation for "shit" doesn't make much sense. "Rayos", on the other hand, is a poor but understandable translation for "shit" if the translator wanted a bowdlerized version. "Rayos", "rayos y centellas", or "truenos, rayos y centellas" is mild swearing. If the original word had been a minced oath such us "shoot" instead of a bold "shit", "rayos" could have been a good translation.

Comment: What are "centellas"? Google translate just transliterates this (giving "centellas" as the translation for "centellas").

Comment: do not ever use google translator. Word reference and Linguee are much better tools.

Comment: Linguee didn't help with that, either...ah, wordreference.com was good: sparks, or greased lightning.

Comment: It's imposible for *shit* to be translated as *rayas*, that's clearly a typo. I've seen it translated as *rayos*. The word you say is not even close.

Comment: "Centella" just means "spark" (English cognate: *scintilla*), or, less frequently, "ball lighting", but it's an expression, so its meaning can't be deduced from the words separately. [In this thread](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/rayos-y-centellas.211666/) there are some good English equivalents like "Holy bill of rights, Batman!" or "Rats! Foiled again!"

Comment: @Yay, I think that you should turn that comment into an answer. It would be up to Clay to accept, but I would upvote your answer, since I think that is the most probable explanation.

Comment: Diego: To be fair, @mdewey was the first to give the right answer. If (s)he doesn't submit an answer in a day or so, I sure will :-)

Comment: @Yay: I wouldn't consider that really as an answer; I'll mark yours as such when/if you post it.

Answer (score 3):

Just to summarise the discussion in comments

We agreed that the writer of the subtitles meant to write *rayos*.

The remaining issue is the thorny question of how you translate obscenities from one language into another bearing in mind the context, the person who said it, the audience and so on. The exclamation 'shit!' is used for disappointment or surprise or a mixture of both. It seems to have lost some of its force over the years and although most careful speakers would not use it in front of children or in a formal setting. Just what the Spanish equivalent is I will leave to the Spanish speakers.